# RDF/XML inputing in schema

Tags: sql, xml, rdf

I can create classes, but seems to fail to identify them and create instances. can any one please help me( I am using https://www.w3.org/RDF/Validator/ to compile )

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE uridef [
  <!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
  <!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
]>

<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="&rdf;" xmlns:rdfs="&rdfs>

<rdfs:Class rdf:ID="Course">
<rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&rdfs;Resource"/>
</rdfs:Class>

<rdf:Property rdf:ID="Name">
<rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Course"/>
<rdfs:range rdf:resource="&rdfs;Literal"/>
</rdf:Property>

<!-- stops here-->

<Course rdf:ID="MIE2001">
<Name>Bla bla bla</Name>
</Course>

</rdf:RDF>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious mistake is:

Change this

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="&rdf;" xmlns:rdfs="&rdfs>
```

to this

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="&rdf;" xmlns:rdfs="&rdfs;">
```

If you remove these lines

```
<Course rdf:ID="MIE2001">
<Name>Bla bla bla</Name>
</Course>
```

...the validation is successfull.

The error here is "Unqualified typed nodes are not allowed".